# Why does a confusion matrix in Orange not show results?

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, orange

I ran a neural network on a data set and when I checked the confusion matrix I got nothing but a message that says: Confusion matrix cannot show regression results.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?